# How can I activate truncate-lines in magit only

Tags: magit, line-truncation

I want to long commit messages to be truncated rather than wrapped around in magit buffers only because I can simply open a commit to see the full message.

I tried

```lisp
(add-hook 'magit-mode-hook (lambda () (setq truncate-lines t)))
```

but that didn't have any effect; `truncate-lines` is still `nil` when I eval it in a magit buffer.

I'm using Spacemacs if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

`truncate-lines` is enabled by default in `magit-mode` buffers, so your hook function isn't actually changing anything.

You need to find what else it is that you'd previously done in your config to prevent that setting from remaining in effect.